# .net IPC channel connection notification

Tags: c#, ipc, remoting

I've created an IPC channel in .NET2 using RegisterWellKnownClientType and RegisterWellKnownServerType.

It doesnt matter whether the server or client is created first - they'll connect to each other once they're both running.

The problem is that the only way I've found to know when the connection is made, is by trying to call a function, and catching the exception if they're not.

Is there an event or something I can hook up to that will tell me when the channel is connected? 
Currently in the client, I use a timer to poll for the connection.

(BTW, i'm not interested in using WCF as we're stuck in .NET2)

Comment: I think the channel will only connect when you use the first IPC over it.  I've had the same trouble and just ended up exception wrapping it.